# How to set fstab file to let Linux AutoMount NTFS with read-write permission

Tags: linux, mount

want to have one folder in windows server 2008 r2 shared to a Linux user with read-write permission.

I put the following sentence int the /etc/fstab file

`//192.168.1.1/sharedFolder /home/myaccount/sharedFolder smbfs rw,users,username=xxx,password=xxx 0 0`

My issue is that only superuser can read and write. normal users cannot write files

How to modify this setting?

Comment: There is no mount option assigning a user to a smbfs (or nfs) mount.
(IMHO is the uid option limited to file systems not supporting user access rights at all.)

Answer (score 0):

The top answer over here should be what you want I think: https://askubuntu.com/questions/72471/correct-way-of-mounting-a-windows-share

```
//192.168.1.1/sharedFolder /home/myaccount/sharedFolder cifs username=xxx,password=xxx,iocharset=utf8,mode=0777,dir_mode=07‌​77 0 0
```